# Share ActionFilter between differents MVC projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, actionfilterattribute

I have to create multiple Asp .Net MVC projects and I want to share common Action Filters (among other things) between these projects in order to avoid repeating code.

For example:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CoreMVC
{
    public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public CustomHandleErrorAttribute() { /* ... */ }

        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

The solution I have thought so far is having this class (and others) in a Class Library project **with a reference to System.Web.MVC** assembly. This way each MVC project can reference this assembly and reuse it.

Is this the proper way to do this or is there any other better solution?

Comment: You have two options, your solution or referencing the source files for the shared code as link files in your MVC projects.  Either will work, but your solution will allow you to more easily share your common code with other MVC projects.

Comment: What your doing is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assemblies/Class libraries is the standard way to share/reuse code in .NET applications so that's one way of doing it. Another way is to use a NuGet which will also contain the assembly with the shared code. The advantage of the NuGet is that you can include some additional stuff along with the class library (such as some bootstrapping Powershell scripts that perform additional customizations to the target project in which you install the NuGet). Another great advantage of a NuGet is that you can have multiple platforms in it and depending on which version/.NET platform you are installing to have the proper assembly getting referenced.

Comment: Consider this as accepted answer. My doubts due to the reference to System.Web/System.Web.MVC in my shared class library

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is available as a NuGet. So you can have your custom NuGet depend on it to better decouple your dependencies. It's not a problem that your class library depends on ASP.NET MVC - this is perfectly normal if it contains ASP.NET MVC action filters.